# Displaying the last value in the table in R

Tags: r, server, datatable, shiny, render

I created a simple application in shiny and I would like the table to display **only the last** visible value. As I marked it in the graphics below in red. My code below:

[image]

```
library(shiny)

mat <- replicate(10, c(sample(c(1000:100), 6, replace = T), sample(NA, 6, replace = T)))
df1 <- data.frame(Month = rep(seq(as.Date("2020-01-03"), by="day", len=12),10,replace = TRUE), 
                  Product = rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = 12), 
                  Value = sample(c(0:300),120, replace = T), 
                  Amount = c(mat),stringsAsFactors = F)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput("All", "Choose", multiple = F, choices = unique(df1$Product)                                          ,
              options = list(`max-options` = 4,size = 10)),
  plotlyOutput('plot'),
  DT::dataTableOutput('tbl2')

)
server <- function(input, output) {

  trend<- reactive({
    df1 %>% 
      filter(Product %in% input$All) %>% 
      arrange(Month) %>% 
      droplevels()
  })
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data=trend(), x=~Month,  y = ~Value,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers') %>%
      add_trace(y = ~Amount, mode = 'lines', yaxis = "y2" , connectgaps = TRUE) %>%
      layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))
  })
      output$tbl2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(trend()[,c(1,2,4)])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)
set.seed(666)
mat <- replicate(10, c(sample(c(1000:100), 6, replace = T), sample(NA, 6, replace = T)))
df1 <- data.frame(Month = rep(seq(as.Date("2020-01-03"), by="day", len=12),10,replace = TRUE), 
                  Product = rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = 12), 
                  Value = sample(c(0:300),120, replace = T), 
                  Amount = c(mat),stringsAsFactors = F)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput("All", "Choose", multiple = F, choices = unique(df1$Product)                                          ,
              options = list(`max-options` = 4,size = 10)),
  plotlyOutput('plot'),
  DT::dataTableOutput('tbl2')

)
server <- function(input, output) {

  trend<- reactive({
    df1 %>% 
      filter(Product %in% input$All) %>% 
      arrange(Month) %>% 
      droplevels()
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data=trend(), x=~Month,  y = ~Value,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers') %>%
      add_trace(y = ~Amount, mode = 'lines', yaxis = "y2" , connectgaps = TRUE) %>%
      layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))
  })
  output$tbl2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    mdata <- trend()[,c(1,2,4)]
    mdata <- tail(mdata[!is.na(mdata$Amount),],1)
    DT::datatable(mdata)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```